# How to remove the RSS feed images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application, i parsed the RSS feed, the feed contains Images & text but i only want to display text only . I don't know how to skip the images from display.

I tried to apply a style to image => display : none. unfortunately it doesn't work. can anyone tell how to do this .

My code is as following :

in controller :

@rss = RSS::Parser.parse(open('http://mysite/entries/rss').read, false)

In my view  :

"<% @rss.items[(0..2)].each do |rss| %>"

"<%= rss.description %> "

"<%end%>"

Comment: If you parse the feed, you filter what you need no? You should provide code sample and rss example

Comment: my rss are , like = @description ="<p> <IMG style=\"WIDT
H: 217px; HEIGHT: 247px\" height=389 hspace=7 src=\"http://myapp/b.jpg
width=335 align=right>". <em> This is the new topic </em> </p>

Comment: i want to remove the img tag and  <em> html tage also . want to display only text here in my case => "This is the new topic"

Answer (score 5):

You could remove the image tags with

```
@description.gsub(/<img .*?>/i, '')
```